# I have to write a function using javascript regex to get a specific output strings from variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to code a function to have some specific output from a variable that stores text inside.

The text is:

> Trying 10.14.206.209... Connected to 10.14.206.209. Escape character is '^]'. -------------------------------------------------- MINI-LINK Traffic Node Command Line Interface -------------------------------------------------- Welcome to AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543 Password: ******** AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543> AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543> AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543> AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543>sh rl status 2 AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543> Slot 2 NEAR END - MMU2 H, RAU2 X 18/16HP Terminal ID A518 Current Output Power 1) 22 dBm, 2) Stand By Current Input Power 1) -46 dBm, 2) -44 dBm Tx Capacity - Modulation 80 Mbit/s - 256QAM Tx Packet Link Capacity 80 Mbit/s Adaptive Modulation Mode Automatic MMU Alarm Status Clear RAU Alarm Status Clear RAU-IF Alarm Status Clear RF Alarm Status Clear Loops Disabled Protection Mode 1+1 Hot Stand By - Manual Active MMU MMU 2 Active Tx Radio Radio 1 Active Rx Radio Radio 1 XPIC Status Disabled Slot 2+3 FAR END - Slot 2+3 in own AMM - MMU2 H, RAU2 X 18/12HP IP Address 10.14.207.17 Terminal ID A517 Current Output Power 1) Stand By, 2) 22 dBm Current Input Power 1) -45 dBm, 2) -44 dBm Tx Capacity - Modulation 80 Mbit/s - 256QAM Tx Packet Link Capacity 80 Mbit/s Adaptive Modulation Mode Automatic MMU-1 Alarm Status Clear MMU-2 Alarm Status Clear RAU-1 Alarm Status Clear RAU-2 Alarm Status Clear RAU-IF 1 Alarm Status Clear RAU-IF 2 Alarm Status Clear RF-1 Alarm Status Clear RF-2 Alarm Status Clear Loops Disabled Protection Mode 1+1 Hot Stand By - Automatic Active MMU MMU 1 Active Tx Radio Radio 2 Active Rx Radio Radio 2 XPIC Status Disabled AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543> AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543>quitConnection to 10.14.206.209 closed by foreign host. ] error=[] systemrc="0" status=""

The end of the text.

Terminal ID's A518 and A517

The slots are 2; 2+3;

The output should be A518 = 2
                     A517 = 2+3

What is the proper code for it?

I've tried to do this with this code:

```js
function ZdorSplitOut() {
  var ZdorOut = "${Zdoroutput}";

  var terminal1 = ZdorOut.split("Terminal ID ")[1].split(" ")[0];
  var terminal2 = ZdorOut.split("Terminal ID ")[2].split(" ")[0];

  var slot1 = ZdorOut.split("Slot ")[1].split(" ")[0];
  var slot2 = ZdorOut.split("Slot ")[2].split(" ")[0];

  var Parsedoutput = {};
  Parsedoutput[terminal1] = slot1;
  Parsedoutput[terminal2] = slot2;
  return Parsedoutput;
}

ZdorSplitOut();
```

The output which is stored in Parsedoutput is 2+3 (and that's all)

I need: A518 = 2
        A517 = 2+3

Comment: Why are you tagging JavaScript as C and M...

Comment: That's not a problem here

Comment: That most certainly **is** a problem. Tagging with something that does not make sense makes 1) well, no sense; 2) people not able to find your question.

Comment: How did you find it?

Comment: Users *follow* certain tags. For users who follow `C`, this question is not relevant.  [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [How do I find topics I'm interested in?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics)

Comment: Because I was looking to answer C questions, which this has **nothing** to do about.

Comment: Sorry about that, i'll edit it.

Comment: Already took care of that, no problem.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract those IDs and numbers with a simple expression such as,

```
Terminal ID\s+(A\d+)|Slot\s+(\S+)
```

and then with some string `concat`s join them however you like to.

```js
const regex = /Terminal ID\s+(A\d+)|Slot\s+(\S+)/gm;
const str = `Trying 10.14.206.209... Connected to 10.14.206.209. Escape character is '^]'. -------------------------------------------------- MINI-LINK Traffic Node Command Line Interface -------------------------------------------------- Welcome to AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543 Password: ******** AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543> AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543> AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543> AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543>sh rl status 2 AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543> Slot 2 NEAR END - MMU2 H, RAU2 X 18/16HP Terminal ID A518 Current Output Power 1) 22 dBm, 2) Stand By Current Input Power 1) -46 dBm, 2) -44 dBm Tx Capacity - Modulation 80 Mbit/s - 256QAM Tx Packet Link Capacity 80 Mbit/s Adaptive Modulation Mode Automatic MMU Alarm Status Clear RAU Alarm Status Clear RAU-IF Alarm Status Clear RF Alarm Status Clear Loops Disabled Protection Mode 1+1 Hot Stand By - Manual Active MMU MMU 2 Active Tx Radio Radio 1 Active Rx Radio Radio 1 XPIC Status Disabled Slot 2+3 FAR END - Slot 2+3 in own AMM - MMU2 H, RAU2 X 18/12HP IP Address 10.14.207.17 Terminal ID A517 Current Output Power 1) Stand By, 2) 22 dBm Current Input Power 1) -45 dBm, 2) -44 dBm Tx Capacity - Modulation 80 Mbit/s - 256QAM Tx Packet Link Capacity 80 Mbit/s Adaptive Modulation Mode Automatic MMU-1 Alarm Status Clear MMU-2 Alarm Status Clear RAU-1 Alarm Status Clear RAU-2 Alarm Status Clear RAU-IF 1 Alarm Status Clear RAU-IF 2 Alarm Status Clear RF-1 Alarm Status Clear RF-2 Alarm Status Clear Loops Disabled Protection Mode 1+1 Hot Stand By - Automatic Active MMU MMU 1 Active Tx Radio Radio 2 Active Rx Radio Radio 2 XPIC Status Disabled AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543> AG-ETN-047-H69229-66543>quitConnection to 10.14.206.209 closed by foreign host. ] error=[] systemrc="0" status=""`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
 if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
  regex.lastIndex++;
 }

 m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
  console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
 });
}
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nHt9xh/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/nHt9xh/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---